# Is there a function like .html that preserves unicodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unicode

For an object in Javascript, I need its XML structure, including all unicodes. The method `.html()` basically fulfills this purpose, but converts the unicodes to html characters. Is there a similar method that does not do this? And if not, is there a list of entities that are converted by `.html()` which one could use to convert them back?

Comment: there is no `.html` function in vanilla js. if you're talking about jquery, then you can use `text()`

Answer (score 0):

You could try javascript `outerHTML` property:

```
document.getElementById('sampleId').outerHTML
```